# Twilio Video. I can display video without sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio

I am testing twillio functionality. The backend(sending tokens, access rights) works fine. In frontend part I get the video from remote participant without sound. We can see eachother. I can't hear him and he can't hear me. How to repair it? I would like to have sound and I would like to have option to mute/unmute sound from my microphone so that the remote participant can't hear me. If you have any other suggestions to my code please let me know.

This is part of my html:

```
     <div class="container" id="conversation">
            <div>
                <video id="localVideo" ></video>
                <video id="patientVideo"></video>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <span>
                        <a href="{% url  'calendar' %}?day={{ request.GET.day }}">
                            <img class="btn" id="call" src="{% static 'images/conversation/Finish-phone-call.png' %}"
                                 alt="call"/></a>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <img class="btn" id="mute" src="{% static 'images/conversation/Icon-microphone-mute-01.png' %}"
                             alt="mute"/>
                        <img class="btn" id="unmute" src="{% static 'images/conversation/Icon-microphone-unmute-01.png' %}"
                             alt="mute"/>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
```

This is part of my javascript. It works. I can connect to the room and I can share videos between participants.:

```
var local_participant;
var videoRoom;

$("#call").click(function () {
    sendNotification("Call canceled");
    if(videoRoom) {
        videoRoom.disconnect();
    }
});

$("#mute").click(function () {
    $(this).hide("fast", function () {
        $("#unmute").show();
        local_participant.audioTracks.forEach(function (audioTrack) {
            audioTrack.enable();
        });
    });
});

$("#unmute").click(function () {
    $(this).hide(function () {
        $("#mute").show();
    });
    local_participant.audioTracks.forEach(function (audioTrack) {
        audioTrack.disable();
    });
});

Twilio.Video.connect(doctor_token, {name: room_name}).then(function (room) {

    videoRoom = room;

    Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack({audio: true}).then(function (localTrack) {
        localTrack.attach("#localVideo");
        room.localParticipant.addTrack(localTrack);
        local_participant = room.localParticipant;
    });

    room.on('participantConnected', function (participant) {
        console.log('Participant connected: ' + participant.identity);
    });

    room.on('participantDisconnected', function (participant) {
        console.log('Participant disconnected: ' + participant.identity);
    });

    room.on('trackAdded', function (track, participant) {
        console.log(participant.identity + " added track: " + track.kind);
        track.attach("#patientVideo");
    });

    room.on('trackRemoved', function (track, participant) {
        console.log(participant.identity + " removed track: " + track.kind);
        track.detach("#patientVideo");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In your code you get the local user's video track by calling:

```
Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack({audio: true})
```

However `createLocalVideoTrack` does not create audio tracks. Instead, you should call [`createLocalTracks`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/global.html#createLocalTracks):

```
Twilio.Video.createLocalTracks()
```

The [default options for `createLocalTracks`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/global.html#CreateLocalTracksOptions) are `{ video: true, audio: true }` so that should be all you need. The promise resolves with an array of `LocalTracks` so you will need to update your callback code too.

```
Twilio.Video.createLocalTracks().then(function (localTracks) {
  localTracks.forEach(function(localTrack) {
    localTrack.attach("#localVideo");
    room.localParticipant.addTrack(localTrack);
  })
  local_participant = room.localParticipant;
});
```

Let me know if that helps!